# Convert byte[] to Base64 string with buffer (to avoid OOM)

Tags: c#, base64

I need to convert a byte array into a Base64 string. Quite an easy task, really. Just do something like this:

```
string resultBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

And it's done, right? Well, not in my case. Apparently, the server this application has to run on has some severe restrictions and an attempt to convert a 20 MB file causes an System.OutOfMemoryException.

I tried to cut the `byteArray` into chunks and get a Base64 string through a buffer.

```
int bufferSize = 3000;
System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i += bufferSize)
{
    int currentBufferSize = Math.Min(bufferSize, byteArray.Length - i);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[currentBufferSize];
    Array.Copy(byteArray, i, buffer, 0, currentBufferSize);
    builder.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(buffer));
}
string resultBase64 = builder.ToString();
```

However, this throws an OOM as well (I believe, because `StringBuilder` creates a new string on `.ToString`, which combined with builder itself causes an OOM).

What is the best way to turn `byte[]` into base64 `string` with minimum use of memory?

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,f9e5bd7b69c5f334) of `Convert.ToBase64String` it looks to me as if that already is the best way to encode the array if you need the entire encoded string in memory.

Comment: builder.TosTring() gets you exactly what you started with.  To reduce memory you may want to compress first.  Convert to Base 64 string increases memory since it is taking a byte and eliminating non printable characters.  Compression may reduce memory size depending on the type of data.

Comment: What are you doing with this string? Is there any way to *not* have a single string, and instead stream the characters somewhere?

Comment: With stringbuilder, you are consuming twice the memory you consumed before (the data in the builder plus the copy of that data returned with `ToString()`). Instead of trying to build the final string, send the chunks down as soon as they appear.

Comment: *" the server this application has to run on have some severe restrictions"* - I'd clarify that. What restrictions? Are you sure server is suitable for .net applications?

Comment: @canton7 I'm sending this string to another server (one I have no power over whatsoever so I'm unable to change anything on the receiving end), it has to be a full Base64 of file.

Comment: @MrScapegrace So you must have some sort of a `NetworkStream`, or a `HttpRequest`, and you perfectly can stream data down into them in chunks.

Comment: @GSerg No can do, this Base64 is included in `json` I send.

Comment: And you send that json using which sending mechanism?

Comment: @GSerg Post-request with HttpWebRequest. OOM is thrown during the construction of json I'm suppose to send.

Comment: So what stops from from calling `.GetRequestStream()` on that and sequentially `Write` the chunks into that stream, first `"{ \"data\": \""`, then the encoded chunks, then `"\"}"`?

Comment: @MrScapegrace How much memory your program is using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Json.NET to turn your object into JSON, it turns out that this *already* supports turning a byte array into a base64-encoded string, and in a way which doesn't take too much memory.

The trick is to make sure that you can stream the generated JSON directly to the HTTP request, rather than generating the entire request in memory before sending it.

```
public class TestModel
{
    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var model = new TestModel() { Bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 } };

    var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("...");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.SendChunked = true;

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
    {
        new JsonSerializer().Serialize(writer, model);
    }
    var response = request.GetResponse();
}
```

The important points here are the `request.SendChunked = true`, and the fact that we open a new `JsonTextWriter` over the stream returned from `request.GetRequestStream()`, and serialize using the `JsonTextWriter`.

Comment: We are using Newtonsoft.Json. I'm not sure how it's going to serialise a byte array, but might as well try it.

Comment: It serializes it as a base64 string. I tested the code above -- after I found it in the source [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/372c396e205a5141c47ed3543b2021f4f396fb2b/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextWriter.cs#L664)

Comment: So it seems. Thank you.